# Show / Hide plotband in Highcharts - Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart with several plotbands. I have added a button to the chart that shows/hides the plotbands. As far as im aware, the only way to do this is to actually add/remove the plotband because plotbands don't have show/hide options (correct me if im mistaken?)

Because the chart has multiple plotbands I have added them to an array. The array of plotbands is then added to the chart. A button then removes or adds them back.

Here's what i've done:

**Creating the plotbands array:**

```
var startDates = [1413417600000, 1412035200000];
var endDates = [1414454400000, 1412208000000];
var id = ['first', 'second'];
var plotBands = [];
var i = 0;

while (i < endDates.length) {
    plotBands.push({
        color: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.4)',
        from: startDates[i],
        to: endDates[i],
        id: id[i]
    });
    i++;
}
```

**Adding the plotbands when the chart is first created:**

```
xAxis: {
    plotBands: plotBands,
    type: 'datetime'
}
```

**Function linked to button to show/hide the plotbands:**

```
var hasPlotBand = true;
    chart = $('#arearange').highcharts();
    $button = $('#button');

$button.click(function () {
    if (!hasPlotBand) {
        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand(plotBands[id=='first']); //this line is not working
        $button.html('Remove plot band');
    } else {
        chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand('first');
        $button.html('Add plot band');
    }
    hasPlotBand = !hasPlotBand;
});
```

The plotbands are added correctly when the chart is initially created. The plotbands are removed correctly using the id='first' to remove the correct bands.

The issue is that im not sure how to re-add the plotbands again, ie: I need to re-add the id='first' bands again. I have tried the following to re-add the bands but neither works:

```
chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand(plotBands[id=='first']);
```

and

```
chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand('first');
```

For testing purposes I also tried to re-add the entire plotbands array (by not trying target a specific id. But that doesn't work either.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can also manipulate on the SVG element.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
        var plotBand = chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0];

        if (plotBand.hidden) {
            plotBand.hidden = false;
            plotBand.svgElem.show();
        } else {
            plotBand.hidden = true;
            plotBand.svgElem.hide();
        }
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/stypmpde/

Comment: Thanks, however the issue comes when you have different plotbands or different parts of the plotbands. What is needed is to only remove a certain part of the plotbands, not all of it. If you check the original post you'll see I have two plot bands, id='first' and id='second'. I need to be able to just remove one part and re-add it. Could you please show an example showing that? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use any loop to find a pltoband with defined ID

Comment: This approach has a problem: every time the chart updates (for example, zooming or resetting the zoom), the hidden SVGs are shown again.

Answer (score 0):

Update to [Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26863909/6355209) fixing the issue that the plotbands are shown again when the chart updates (hide other series or zoom):

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var plotBand = chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0];

    if (plotBand.hidden) {
        plotBand.hidden = false;
        plotBand.svgElem.element.style.opacity = 1;
        plotBand.svgElem.element.style['pointer-events'] = 'all';
    } else {
        plotBand.hidden = true;
        plotBand.svgElem.element.style.opacity = 0;
        plotBand.svgElem.element.style['pointer-events'] = 'none';
    }
});
```